# increment existing db columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, insert, auto-increment, identity

I am trying to make a exact copy of a table but change the values of 2 columns. Basically I have 800 entries in the db table and need 800 more but i need the value of one of the columns (Set_id to be 11) and I need the value of another to auto increment...but the column isnt identity insert unfortunately.  I created a temp table and copied existing table into temp table. I then am trying to write the temp table back to the original table with that one column as an 11 and trying to make the doctype id column start with 860 and then each entry auto increment with one. I created this cursor:

```
declare @id int, @document char(30)
select @id = 860
declare documents cursor for
/* This will select all Non-Physician users */
  select tag from cabinet..document_names

open documents

fetch next from documents into @document
while @@fetch_status <> -1
begin
 select @id = @id +1
      if not exists (select * from cabinet..document_names where set_id='11' and tag=@document)
      insert into cabinet..document_names (TAG, TAGORDER, ACTIVE,QUEUE, REASON, FORM,DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,SIGN_X,
SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,doctype_id,CODE,CALCTABLE_ID, DOC_TYPE,SET_ID,SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period , DocHdrLength,DocHdrSearchString,DocFtrLength,DocFtrPageNo,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason)
select TAG, TAGORDER, ACTIVE,QUEUE, REASON, FORM,DIRECT_VIEW,GLOBAL,FU_SIGN,SIGN_X,
SIGN_Y,SIGN_W,SIGN_H,ANNOTATE,@ID,CODE,CALCTABLE_ID, DOC_TYPE,'11',SUSPEND_DELAY,Text_Editing,Restrict_Viewing,Viewing_Expire,
Viewing_Period , DocHdrLength,DocHdrSearchString,DocFtrLength,DocFtrPageNo,DocRuleId,Outbound,SigQueue,SigReason from
cabinet..document_names_temp 


fetch next from documents into @document

end
close documents 
deallocate documents
```

It is doing exactly what I want except the doctype id repeats itself as 861, 861 etc etc. I need that number to increment by one after each entry into original table. Any help on where I am messing up is apprecaited! thanks!

Comment: I am using SQL server management studio 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
  INSERT INTO cabinet..document_names ([columns])
  SELECT [columns] 
  FROM cabinet..document_names_temp
```

have a `WHERE` statement as well? something like

```
  INSERT INTO cabinet..document_names ([columns])
  SELECT [columns] 
  FROM cabinet..document_names_temp 
  WHERE TAG = @Document
```

Currently your insert just inserts each record it can find in `document_names_temp` with `doctype_id` set to `@ID` which would explain the repetition of 861, 861, 861.. you probably have the same amount of records with `docttype_id` 862 as well.

Comment: I am one step closer....thanks Byte....I did what you said so code and put that where clause on the end...it worked, kinda, the doctypeid increments by two for some reason, so 860 then 862 then 864, so on so on....do I have the select@id=@id+1 in the wrong place? I tried moving it around but couldnt get it working still

Comment: The only thing I can imagine is that the cursor you create contains the each tag twice. The `select @id = @id + 1` is ok, but having duplicates in your cursor would explain why it "adds 2" to each id. You'd have 2 increments and 1 insert for each tag....

Comment: what do you mean the "each tag". I wasnt sure if you were talking about the fetch next from documents into@document part? I took one out but still same thing. Weird how it goes from 860 to 862 and 864 but doesnt fill in 861 863 etc etc

Comment: What i mean is that `declare documents cursor for select tag from cabinet..document_names` generates a cursor with duplicates (I said tag because you select tag there). Say your cursor contains ["tag1", "tag1","tag2","tag2"]. The first "tag1" is processed, @Id is incremented and "tag1" is inserted, the second "tag1" gets processed, @id is incremented but it does not get inserted as it already exists in the destination table.... I'm not saying that this is what is happening, but it's the only way I can think of that this is happening at the moment.

Comment: ahhhhh gotcha!! I changed it to
declare documents cursor for

  select distinct(tag) from cabinet..document_names

and voila, it worked great....thanks so much!!!  I appreciate your follow ups and help!

Comment: Glad I could help you out.